# Get device orientation (alpha, beta, gamma) without using listener?

Tags: javascript, html, device-orientation

I'm using `window.DeviceOrientationEvent` to listen for changes in the device orientation. However, I want to calibrate my application to report orientation changes *relative*  to the original orientation. In order to do this I have come up with the following solution:

```
originalOrientation.freeze = false;
window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', function(e){
            var orientation = {g: Math.round(e.gamma), b: Math.round(e.beta), a: Math.round(e.alpha), o: window.orientation || 0};
            if(!originalOrientation.freeze){
                originalOrientation = orientation;
                originalOrientation.freeze = true;
            }
        });
```

This essentially takes the first value returned by the `deviceorientation` listener and "freezes" it so it doesn't keep updating. I don't like this method because I'd rather do the calibration elsewhere in my code, instead of the place where the actual orientation is gathered. I also don't want to attach the listener twice because the value returned in the callback will be lost.

TLDR;

Is there a way I can call something like `window.getDeviceOrientation()` to return the alpha, beta, and gamma values synchronously instead of attaching a callback?

Answer (score 2):

I think the [full-tilt](https://github.com/adtile/Full-Tilt) library would achieve this for you.

There's a simple example on the github page that shows how you initialise their promises based library, then in your logic, you just check that the device orientation object exists (IE the promise was fulfilled) before calling a method such as `deviceOrientation.getScreenAdjustedEuler()`.

You don't have to be using an animation loop like in their example.

As an aside, you could have added and removed the event listeners without losing your data. I definitely would have done that rather than disable the listener with the freeze. I was adding and removing listeners as required for a while to get the initial state to compare with later when constant updates were needed (or more accurately not subscribing to the event when they weren't needed). I'd still go with full-tilt though. I used it because it provides normalised data across devices but it does pretty much what you want and would probably make your code a little neater.

If you're still working on it 5 months later that is, yeah this is probably of more use to someone hunting around now.